# email data from a form to an email address

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple form. All i want to do is email the data to an email address. Is there a way I could do that just using JQuery or javascript? Can I do this without php or any other server side language? Is it doable or I am just thinking out loud

Comment: No, you cannot send an email via JavaScript.  You could add a mailto link with the body pre-loaded with the data but this requires the user to have a default email client set up.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I could do that just using JQuery or javascriopt?

No.

> Can I do this without php or any other server side language?

Not in [a way reliable enough to use on the WWW](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

You need a server side process. There are some third party hosted ones out there.

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like I was day dreaming indeed

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just thinking out loud... for a few reasons:

1. If you COULD do this, you wouldn't want to; you'd be exposing your SMTP relay, username/password, and recipient email address in client-side javascript/jQuery code (viewable by anyone with access to your page
2. You can't do this without some server-side code which knows how to interact with an SMTP.

There might be services out there (which would make up your server-side part of this)... I don't know any off hand though.